# Which is the most used/popular version of Chorme browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I have to apply a fix to my website, but the best approach will only will work for Chrome versions 58+ .

I wonder how popular is this version? i.e. How many users will get the bug in my website fixed.

Is there any analytics on browsers versions usage?

Thanks

Comment: Well I'd expect the analytics to be available for *your* web site. Global figures won't be nearly as useful as the figures for your specific site, and you're the one with access to those...

Comment: Sure, but if we have a global figures for different browsers, why not for different versions of the same browser...

Comment: And those figures may well be available, but a) they're likely to be slightly delayed; b) they're likely to be less useful than for your specific audience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chrome auto updates so I wouldn't worry about it.